# smooth dependence of stable manifold on parameters

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Let $v$ be a $C^r$ vector field on a Banach space $V$ such that $0$ is its hyperbolic fixed point, and let $X_v\subset V$ be its local stable manifold. Does $X_v$ depend on $v$ smoothly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes: please see the subsection "Differentiable dependence of invariant manifolds and foliations on diffeomorphisms" (page 164) of Appendix 1 of Palis-Takens book "Hyperbolicity and sensitive chaotic dynamics at homoclinic bifurcations" (see, e.g., this link http://books.google.fr/books/about/Hyperbolicity_and_Sensitive_Chaotic_Dyna.html?id=pwydPA23KVUC&redir_esc=y towards Google books). Here, the results are stated for diffeomorphisms but the arguments can be adapted to the case of vector fields.